# How do I get my school funded?

Tags: funding, education

I have built a school where English, Mathematics and Georgian language are taught to minorities living in the Republic of Georgia.  I named the school as "Alternative Education Center".  This is (09-27-2019) our second year, and last year we had an average 50 students.  For me, the school is non-profit, which means I have not taken money for myself, but the school is a registered business entity in Georgia.

ATM offers good quality education for the lowest possible tuition, and we have been paying our teachers twice more than public schools in Georgia.

This year, I am planning to offer IT courses, which includes software and web development lessons.  Plus, we will open a "tech park" where young minds gather and develop their projects.

However, we have three classes with very limited conditions. The land where our school is belongs to a friend, and he is willing to donate the land to ATM, but I need funding to construct a new building that will fit to education standard.

How do I find funding?!

Comment: Welcome to AcademiaSE! This is an interesting question and an ambitious goal. But I'm a bit surprised: if the school is a non-profit, why is it registered as a business entity? I don't know the law in Georgia but isn't there a charity status which would allow the school to accept donations? Also I assume that there are government subsidies for education institutions, right?

Comment: I can't tell if this is a primary school or a tertiary school.  You need either a loan, a donation, or a government grant, and I don't see how we can figure that out for you.

Comment: There is one possible source of funding that might be available: a NGO (Non Governmental Organization). The UN has an office to support such organizations and you might use them to find something open to you. Start a [search on this page](https://outreach.un.org/ngorelations/content/dpi-ngo-resource-centre) but click some of the links there to learn more, including their home page.